# What is the difference between "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Classes"

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios6

I am not able to understand the difference between Auto layout and Size classes, If some can help.

Answer (score 2):

The two terms are not really opposites of each other, autolayout manages how views are layed out relative to each other, while size classes is an alternative to specifying different layouts for each device screen size.

so autolayouts are used in tandem with size classes (or can still be used if not using size classes)

Comment: Still unable to figure out the difference and what to use when.  :(

Comment: can maybe think of it like this, autolayout will help you make your app layout properly between all the different iPhone sizes, size classes will allow you to make one layout in the storyboard that will work for both iphone and ipad, but still let you tweak some differences between the two. size classes basically save you from having to make an iphone and an ipad layout